# Python: isPrime function will print too many answers

Tags: python, for-loop

The problem is that my code prints

```
"The number you entered is prime"
```

a lot of times depending on the number I enter, followed by

```
"That number is not prime"
```

if the number isn't prime. I know WHY it's doing this (it's because the if statement keeps looping back with the for loop until it finds a number that divides evenly, then it prints the "not prime" result), but the question I'm asking is HOW do I fix it?

```
def isprime(n):
try:
    npnc = "Neither prime nor composite"
    if isinstance(n, complex) == True:
        print("Sorry, trial division doesn't like negative numbers. Try again.")
    elif n == 0:
        return npnc
    elif n == 1:
        return npnc
    else:
        for m in range(2, (int(n**.5)+1)):
            if n%m == 0:
                print("That number is not prime")
                break
            elif n%m > 0:
                print("The number you entered is prime")
```

Note: It does have an "except ValueError" piece that I did not include.

Comment: Can I suggest a sub-function without all those silly checks?

Comment: Don't compare to boolean literals; just use `if isinstance(n, complex):`.

Comment: A better check would be to see if `n.imag` exists and is non-zero, since 2+0j is still the prime integer 2, even if it is represented in its equivalent complex form. And in that case, you can simply return `False`, as only a pure integer can be a prime number.

Comment: @chepner I usually compare to boolean literals because I think it is more readable especially in other languages. Is this a bad practice?

Comment: Yes; as a general rule, function names beginning with `is` already return a Boolean value, so it is redundant to compare it to Boolean just to form *another* Boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for..else` in this situation. If you don't break out of the loop then the program executes the `else` part after the `for`.

```
for m in range(2, (int(n**.5)+1)):
    if n%m == 0:
        print("That number is not prime")
        break
else:
    print("number is prime")
```

is identical to:

```
found = False
for m in range(2, (int(n**.5)+1)):
    if n%m == 0:
        print("That number is not prime")
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    print("number is prime")
```

[docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your function - decomposing the task is always nice, and in *this* case it allows early returns:

```
def isprime_impl(n):
    for m in range(2, (int(n**.5)+1)):
        if n%m == 0:
            return False
    return True
```